# Javascript formula syntax not working

Tags: javascript, html, math, syntax, javascript-objects

I have the following formula and am trying to convert this to JavaScript:

```
=(x*(y/120000)*(1+(y/120000))^(z))/((1+(y/120000))^z-1)
```

I have used the following, but I don't think the syntax is correct, but I cannot work out why!

```
var price = ((parseInt(x.value)*(parseInt(y.value)/1200)*(Math.pow(1+parseInt(y.value)/12000)),parseInt(z.value))) / (Math.pow((1+(parseInt(y.value)/1200),(parseInt(z.value)-1)));
```

My whole form script is as follows:

```
<form name="priceCalc" action="">
  <div align="center">
    <select name="loanamount" onchange="price();">
      <option value="130000">£130,000</option>
      <option value="160000">£160,000</option>
    </select>

    <select name="interestrate" onchange="price();">
      <option value="449">4.49%</option>
      <option value="500">5%</option>
    </select>

    <select name="numberpayments" onchange="price();">
      <option value="480">40yrs</option>
      <option value="360">30yrs</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <div id="prices">Change items to see price</div>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
  function price() {
    var x = document.priceCalc.loanamount;
    var y = document.priceCalc.interestrate;
    var z = document.priceCalc.numberpayments;

    var price = ((parseInt(x.value)*(parseInt(y.value)/1200)*(Math.pow(1+parseInt(y.value)/12000)),parseInt(z.value))) / (Math.pow((1+(parseInt(y.value)/1200),(parseInt(z.value)-1)));

    document.getElementById("prices").innerHTML = 'Price: ' + price;
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: there isn't a matching `)` for `(Math.pow`

Comment: `x.value = parseInt(x.value)` and so on would make your JS formula easier to read and avoid calling `parseInt` so many times.

Comment: As a side not look into code editor, a good editor would have highlighted the fact that your `()` were not matching saving you some trouble :)

Comment: or just `var x = parseInt (x.value)`

Comment: I tried adding x.value = parseInt(x.value); y.value = parseInt(y.value); z.value = parseInt(z.value) but when I call this it shows: [object HTMLSelectElement]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=(x*(y/120000)*(1+(y/120000))^(z))/((1+(y/120000))^z-1)
```

Translates into something like

```
var x = parseInt(x.value,10), 
    y = parseInt(y.value,10)/120000, 
    z = parseInt(z.value,10)*12; // from your comments


var price = ( x*y*Math.pow(1+y,z) ) / (Math.pow(1+y,z)-1);
document.getElementById("prices").innerHTML ='Monthly repayment: £' + price.toFixed(2);
```

Here is it with your code

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.priceCalc.loanamount.onchange = price;
  document.priceCalc.interestrate.onchange = price;
  document.priceCalc.numberpayments.onchange = price;

}

function price() {

    var x = parseInt(document.priceCalc.loanamount.value, 10);
    var y = parseInt(document.priceCalc.interestrate.value, 10) / 12000; 
    var z = parseInt(document.priceCalc.numberpayments.value,10)*12;

    var repayment = (x * y * Math.pow(1 + y, z)) / (Math.pow(1 + y, z) - 1); 
    console.log(x,y,z,x * y * Math.pow(1 + y, z),(Math.pow(1 + y, z) - 1),repayment)
  
    document.getElementById("prices").innerHTML = 'Monthly repayment: £' + isFinite(repayment) && !isNaN(repayment) && repayment != Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY?repayment.toFixed(2):"0.00";
}
```

```html
<form name="priceCalc" action="">
  <div align="center">

    <select name="loanamount">
      <option value="0">Please select</option>
      <option value="130000">£130,000</option>
      <option value="160000">£160,000</option>
    </select>

    <select name="interestrate">
      <option value="0">Please select</option>
      <option value="449">4.49%</option>
      <option value="500">5%</option>
    </select>

    <select name="numberpayments">
      <option value="0">Please select</option>
      <option value="480">40yrs</option>
      <option value="360">30yrs</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <div id="prices">Change items to see price</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That gives me results, but they are WAY off what the answers should be? I am not quite sure what the you are doing there with the `x = parseInt(x.value,10),` what does the 10 relate to please?

Comment: That is the radix. If you enter 08 or 09, it can parse as octal. Please see the updated code

Comment: I see changing z does not do much. Perhaps the actual calculation is incorrect, but as far as I can see I converted your calculation correctly

Comment: The original formula works perfectly if that helps?: =(x*(y/120000)*(1+(y/120000))^(z))/((1+(y/120000))^z-1)

Comment: I am not sure what 120000 or 480 means. If it is days or seconds? Currently the difference between 40 and 30 years are on the 7th decimal. Please note JS time is not Excel time

Comment: The whole form is meant to work out amortized loan repayments. So x = loan amount, y = % interest charged, z = time period (months). The 120000 is being used to divide the interest payment from an annual integer (i.e. 500 to represent 5%) to a monthly figure (i.e. 0.4166% per month). z should make a significant difference to the result, as this is the time period the loan is taken over, and will affect the amortization.

Answer (score 1):

```
var price = ((parseInt(x.value)*(parseInt(y.value)/120000)*(Math.pow(1+parseInt(y.value)/120000),parseInt(z.value))) / (Math.pow((1+(parseInt(y.value)/120000),(parseInt(z.value)-1)))));
```

Also, in your top line you have `/120000` but in your calculation you have `/1200`

Also as per gillesc's suggestion:

```
var x = parseInt(x.value);
var y = parseInt(y.value);
var z = parseInt(z.value);
var price = ((x*(y/120000)*(Math.pow((1+y)/120000),z)) / (Math.pow((1+(y/120000),(z-1)))));
```

Comment: The following still does not work?  'var price = ((parseInt(x.value)*(parseInt(y.value)/1200)*(Math.pow(1+parseInt(y.value)/1200),parseInt(z.value))) / (Math.pow((1+(parseInt(y.value)/1200),(parseInt(z.value)-1)))));'

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? try the newly edited one, i have added a bracket for `1+y` which should also solve a mathematical issue

Comment: Sorry it is still not working? This is the original excel formula if that helps? **=(D2*(C5/120000)*(1+(C5/120000))^(H2))/((1+(C5/120000))^H2-1)**  where: D2=x C5=y H2=z

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below updated formula :-

```
  var price = ((parseInt(x.value) * (parseInt(y.value) / 1200) * (Math.pow(((parseInt(1) + parseInt(y.value) / 12000)), parseInt(z.value)))) / (Math.pow((parseInt(1) + (parseInt(y.value) / 1200)), (parseInt(z.value) - 1))));
```

Comment: Have you replace the whole line which I have sent to you? Please replace the whole line as above, also Please clear your cache and check this again. Its working

Comment: Still does not work. If you change value z, it does not affect result? This is original excel formula **=(D2*(C5/120000)*(1+(C5/120000))^(H2))/((1+(C5/120000))^H2-1)** D2=x C5=y H2=z

Answer (score 0):

I found a way in the end:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = repayment;

}

function repayment() {

  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.value, 10) / 120000;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;

  var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

  document.getElementById("repayments").innerHTML = 'Monthly repayment: £' + repayment.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form name="repaymentcalc" action="">
  <div align="center">
    </br>
    Loan Amount
    <select name="loanamount">
      <option value="100000">£100,000</option>
      <option value="200000">£200,000</option>
      <option value="300000">£300,000</option>
      <option value="400000">£400,000</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    Interest Rate
    <select name="interestrate">
      <option value="100">1.00%</option>
      <option value="200">2.00%</option>
      <option value="300">3.00%</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    Term
    <select name="numberpayments">
      <option value="5">5yrs</option>
      <option value="10">10yrs</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <br>
    <div id="repayments">Monthly repayment: £837.85</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That could have been my code with the right amendments. See my update

Comment: Yes, sorry. I got confused by the maths for a while, and then it must have been your code I ended up amending!

Comment: I added test for infinity and NAN while changing the values.